# Do While Error, Autofill code

Tags: vba, excel, while-loop, autofill

I am having a Debug Error (Do While) when trying to run the code below.
The intent of this code is to look at a list (column A in sheet5) and add and/or replace in column A of sheet2. if need to add new, also insert a entire row. 
Another thing is that I would like to Autofill formulas from B2:G2 until the last row with contents in column A.

```
Sub AddNewPO()
    Dim Sheet5 As Worksheet
    Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

    Set Sheet5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New_POs")
    Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary by PO")

    LastRow5 = Sheet5.Cells(Sheet5.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Lastrow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    i = 1
    Do While Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value
         i = i + 1
    Loop

    For j = i To LastRow5
        Lastrow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheet2.Rows(Lastrow2 + 2).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheet2.Range("A" & Lastrow2 + 1).Value = Sheet5.Range("A" & j).Value
    Next j

    Sheet5.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: in the Do While.....

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite `Do` loop, so add another exit condition like

`If i > LastRow5 Or i > Lastrow2 Then Exit Do`

To copy formulas use this:

```
 Sheet2.Range("B2:G2").Copy  'Copy formulas
 Sheet2.Range("B3:G" & Lastrow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
```

---

.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddNewPO()
    Dim Sheet5 As Worksheet, LastRow5 As Long, i As Long
    Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet, Lastrow2 As Long, j As Long

    Set Sheet5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("New_POs")
    Set Sheet2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary by PO")
    LastRow5 = Sheet5.Cells(Sheet5.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Lastrow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    i = 1
    Do While Sheet5.Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheet2.Cells(i, 1).Value
         i = i + 1
         If i > LastRow5 Or i > Lastrow2 Then Exit Do
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For j = i To LastRow5
        Lastrow2 = Sheet2.Cells(Sheet2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Sheet2.Rows(Lastrow2 + 2).EntireRow.Insert
        Sheet2.Range("A" & Lastrow2 + 1).Value = Sheet5.Range("A" & j).Value
    Next j
    Sheet2.Range("B2:G2").Copy  'Copy formulas
    Sheet2.Range("B3:G" & Lastrow2).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
    Sheet5.Activate
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 End Sub
```

Comment: That works!! Thanks. Now how do I get the formulas from B2 to G2 copy down?

Comment: Nope. On sheet2, after this previous code gets done I would like to copy down formulas from B2:G2 until Lastrow2 of columnA

Comment: One final question, I have 4 different codes in the same excel and I use one button for each but they are sequential. How can I combine them with one button/

Comment: You can create one more Sub (Sub 5 let's say), and from this new sub you call all the other 4 subs, this way you can assign Sub5 to one button and execute all 4

Comment: One is really short (just to sort), another one is looking for unique values (just as the one we did), and the one we did

Comment: how do you recommend to do this?

Comment: I can't explain it in details in comments - open a new question and I'll give you a short example